# error: expected expression before ‘=’ token

Tags: c, arrays, operators

This is the error I'm getting:

```
c:17:15: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token
             suma + = mat[N][M];
```

And this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 3
#define M 3

int mat[N][M]i,j,k,l,m,n;
int vector[N];
int suma; 

int main (void){
   for(i=0;i<N;i++){
     for(j=0;j<M;j++){
       printf("Enter a number: ");
       scanf("%d", &mat[N][M]);
     }
   }
   for(k=0;k<N;k++){
      suma=0;
     for(l=0;l<M;l++){
       **suma+ = mat[N][M];
     }
     vector[i]=suma;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+=   !=   + =
```

Meaning: just write: `suma += mat[N][M];`
 ............................................^  no space.

For the sake of completeness I will add what Sourav mentioned:
You need to reset `i` (`i=0`) after the first `for` loop, to avoid accessing out of bounds memory and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: you missed the indexing part. :)

Comment: You are right, although tbh I didn't look for that since the question seemed clear :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the compiler issue, `+=` and `+ =` are not the same thing. You should use `+=` without the space in between.

I believe that `**suma` is a *typo* in your code. (or a missed attempt to format).

That said, your program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In the later loop,

```
vector[i]=suma;
```

You did not reset `i`. It will try to access out of bound memory.

Either you need to use `k` as index or, reset `i` and increment that as needed.

Comment: You refer to put **vector [k] +=suma;**??

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R nope, `vector [k] = suma;`